# Archiving Workflow History

Tags: workflow

Alright.  I am very very new to using Sharepoint in any capacity.  I have set up an Engineering Change process in our company Sharepoint so that people can create a change request.  I can then send that out for approvals and keep track of it through the process.  The workflow history shows me what I need as far as who approved, when they approved, etc.  I need a way to try and archive this or export it to some sort of document since Sharepoint deletes the workflow history after so long.  I need to keep it logged for auditing or until this process is moved over to Windchill sometime further in the future.  I have seen recommendations as far as coding this and such but honestly that is pretty foreign to me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated from you pros.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The history list is not what you should use for this. The entries linking to the workflow will be removed (by a timer job) and you wont be able to access the data anymore. (the data is still there, but you will loose the ID's needed to access them)

If you need to persist some information from the workflow you should consider writing it to an alternate location in the workflow itself.